# Black Screen of Death at startup; no cursor, no BIOS, no safe mode

Tags: windows-10, boot, drivers, bsod, dell-latitude

I was asked to install Windows 10 on a Dell Latitude D630 running Windows 8.1. After the installation I went to [dell.com](http://www.dell.com) to download drivers. I've noticed this message from Dell:

> Product not tested for Windows 10 upgrade
>
> Dell is not testing or developing Windows 10 drivers for this product. If you choose to upgrade, some features, applications, and connected devices may not work as expected.

I installed Driver pack v17 which installed a few compatible drivers like display, Network & sound drivers, but the chipset drivers failed, I tried 3 times but still did not install.

Today the laptop got the BSOD (Blue Screen of Death). I tried to read the error but I was too late & the PC restarted.

When starting up, it hanged on the black screen just before showing the lock screen & so she force shutdown it using the power button & start it up again the I noticed that on the windows logo this time the loading was different, the usual circling 5 dots weren't there but they were scattered horizontally in the middle of the screen then after the loading it again hang on the lock screen but this time I could see the lock screen wallpaper behind a pinkish transparent screen, after a few seconds the screen responded & she entered her password & started doing what she was doing.

After 5 minutes a notification popped up saying "the display driver Intel HD Graphics crushed & was recovered" something like that. Then within a few minutes the display froze and I told her not to do anything because I wanted to see if that error will show up again but nothing, so after waiting for 15min, the screen back light went off & after touching the touchpad, it came back on but still frozen & now with a screen, again another force shutdown the PC then failed to start up, only a black screen when the power button is pressed.

After starting it up & shutting it down several times it finally powered up but without loading several drivers & one of those drivers was the display driver & other drivers under UNKNOWN. I then made a bootable windows 8.1 installation from my laptop onto a FLASH DRIVE, plugged it to her PC then I opened Explorer, Flash drive with Win8.1, Sources, then I launched the setup.exe in that folder then it said SETUP IS COPYING TEMPORARY FILES.

After that I agreed the Terms then I Clicked on ADVANCED & chose Drive C where windows 10 was installed. Step 1 completed the step 2 went passed half then  it said SETUP WILL CONTINUE INSTALLATION AFTER RESTARTING PC, i let it count down to zero but then after restarting i just hanged on a black screen with no DELL SPLASH SCREEN, NO WINDOWS BOOT SCREEN. I can't even access the BIOS.

Anyone who knows how to deal with this kind of problem please help.

### Reply

It's a black screen with back-light. Here is a link for you 
http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19483790
check it out to see what we are dealing with here. I tried all the methods given but still nothing changed .Also check out the video on YouTube entitled "D630 - Fix Black Screen". This guy solved his by heating the Nvidia Graphics card with a blow torch but that's a risk I don't want to take unless I'm out of options.

Comment: Too much and one ugly blob of a question.... Please clean this up. Take out the HD and see if it'll boot without HD. Same with memory modules too. Process of elimination on the hardware aspects until you can get a screen to troubleshoot further. Be sure the power button is turned to the one position, the switch is up on your wall, the surge protector switch is on, and that it is plugged into a working electrical source as well.... That's one UGLY question.

Comment: "but this time I could see the lock screen wallpaper behind a pinkish transparent screen" ... "the display driver Intel HD Graphics crushed & was recovered", sounds like a hardware failure.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are 4 different Dell Latitude D630 models:

1. Latitude D630
2. Latitude D630ATG
3. Latitude D630XFR
4. Latitude D630C

The latest OS these models hardware support is [Windows Vista](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/latitude-d630/drivers?ref=autocomplete). We're not even talking Windows 7 here. It's clear that Windows 10 will not run properly on any of this hardware.

The best way would be to install the latest OS your hardware support and download officially available drivers from Dell. This way you will be somewhat sure that all the hardware components are properly communicating with OS.

Comment: I managed to solve the black screen with back light problem. You can follow this YouTube Video link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SI6C307oVkk & follow what this person did. I didn't have the things requested in the video, instead I used the wax candle to heat the silver part of the Nvidia graphics chip for about 3-4 minutes & left it to cool. After it cooled i then brushed off the black staff left by the wax candle then I plugged in the keyboard, the screen & inserted the battery & when I pressed the power button the laptop went ON & it continued installing Windows 8.1 from where it left.

Comment: Until this is witchery, based on your experience in research and computer maintenance you probably would be better off going to service center in the near time. You have just forcefully applied heat to the nVidia graphics card and brushed off "black staff" (where _staff_ should probably be _stuff_). You don't have any officially supported drivers for any Windows later than Vista, expect most of the laptop functionality to be gone as your Windows 8.1 installation will be completed.

Comment: I visited the Nvidia website where I found the Nvidia Graphic driver for Windows 8.1 For Dell models D630, D630c and other models i don't remember. Before installing the Graphic drivers I downloaded the Drivers from the Dell website & chose WIndows Vista as my OS then I downloaded the BIOS update  and installed it then the Nvidia diver followed up. Certain Vista drivers as able to install on Windows 8.1 (though I think almost all of them are compatible with Windows 8.1 because most of them installed without any errors or problems without using Compatibility Mode).